# Can I migrate my SSL certificate to windows SBS 2008?

Tags: certificate, windows-sbs-2008

I have currently on my windows SBS 2003 box an SSL certificate for www.mydomain.com. I understand that for the 2008 SBS box I need a certificate for remote.mydomain.com. Can I simply export and import the certificate, or must I contact the issuer to get a changed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Zypher's answer is true (I received an email from comodo that they will not edit my old certificate to remote.mydomain.com), it seems that it is possible to change the default remote access url to www.mydomain.com: In the get an internet address wizard at the page where you have to fill in your domain name you can click on advanced options: there you can set the prefix for your domain to "www." in stead of the default "remote." It possibly causes other connectivity problems, but for now I can live with it.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to get a certificate for remote.mydomain.com. Certificates are specific to the FQDN (with the exceptions of wildcard certs), so you would get errors when you tried to connect with that cert. Although depending on what you are doing a self signed cert might be just fine. Is this just for RDP or Webmail type setups?

EDIT (RE Win Mobile Devices):

You don't have to pay for a cert, You just need to get your root CA's public cert into the certificate store. I used to do this two ways:

1. Create a simple installer for the cert ( I can dig this up if you want an example) and put it on a public website, then just browse to it and install OTA.
2. Put the Cert on an microSD card, toss that int he device and when you click on the cert it will prompt to import.

Comment: I want to be able to synchronize windows mobile 6.x devices, that demands a trusted certificate if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This is because the "CN" or "Common Name" of the certificate has changed, and no provider will permit you to change the CN. Some will allow you to cancel the cert and submit a new one within 7 days but I'm guessing this has well and truely passed for you now...

Comment: thanks for your added reply. I am quite a NOOB at server administration and I would need to be taken by the hand to see how the things you describe are done.